# Is it possible to let a Node.js application receive user input data in an external text editor?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I'm writing an application for Node.js. I want to execute an external text editor like VSCode and wait until a user inputs any texts and saves them. After that, the app receives the saved data from the text editor as stdin. I mean that it is action same as `git commit[ENTER]`.

I tried to use `open [path to app]` command but it didn't work well. The process exits with no wait.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: https://www.npmjs.com/package/external-editor

Comment: Thanks @Quentin. I tried it but didn't work well. Console editors like vim work well but editors like VSCode seem like not to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need an external library for this. You can launch the program using [child_process.spawn](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options), and then wait for changes to the file using [fs.watch](https://nodejs.org/api/all.html#fs_fs_watch_filename_options_listener). When a change comes in (or when the editor is closed), you can read the file again.

Code (untested):

```
import {spawn} from "child_process";
import fs from "fs";

function getEditorInput(editorCmd, file, cb) {
  const process = spawn(editorCmd, [file]);

  process.on('close', (code) => {
    // re-read file, and cb
  });
  // OR
  const watcher = fs.watch(file, (ev, f) => {
    // re-read file, call cb
  })
}
```

Note you should close the watcher at some point (say, after editor closes) with `watcher.close()`.

Comment: Thanks @functorial. I see. Is it necessary to create a temporary file for this action, isn't it? I'm trying it. Thanks.

Comment: @takanopontaro this method should work for any file, but using a temporary file is a good practice.